# passing Class of an runtime object to a generics-field in java

Tags: java, class, types, casting, containers

I'm working on an Entity-System. My Components do contain an ArrayList of Value-Objects, so that i can build Components at runtime.
Here's my Value-class:

```
public class Value<V> implements Cloneable{

    private V value = null;
    private String name;
    public Value()
{
}

public Value(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public V getValue()
{
    return value;
}

public void setValue(V value)
{
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    return name.equals(((Value)o).name);
}

@Override
public Value clone()
{
    return new Value<V>(new String(name));
}
}
```

Let's say i want to fill a Value-Object with an Double (this works):

```
Value<Double> v = new Value<Double>("xCoordinate");
```

Why can't i do this:

```
Object o = new Double(42);
Value<o.getClass()> v = new Value<o.getClass>("theAnswer");
```

I want to pass the class of the Object "o" to the type Variable if Value, why can't i get the class from the runtime representation of "o".

Comment: Is the 42/theAnswer pair from Douglas Adams?

Comment: Well, obviously it is...

Comment: Type names as used in generic declarations are not `Class` objects.

Comment: This is not possible. Compiler needs to know the type at compile time. If you add details for which problem you are trying to solve, maybe we can help there

Comment: I want to store objects, such as an integer, String or BoundingBox in an Container with a nametag. The Container should not return Objects but integers, etc. depending on what you did put in. I want to do this to avoid casting before using the Value in the container. The Container class is the "Value" class above!

Comment: Oh, and what is most important is, that these container-objects are stored in an arraylist, this is why generics do not work for different objects right now

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done, becuase the compiler erases all generic type reference. The virtual machine doens't know that generics exist, except for field and method declarations.

If this is what you want to do, imitate the compiler and use the following:

```
Object o = new Double(42);
Value v = new Value("theAnswer");
```

You will get comipiler warnings, and you will have to cast return values. If you don't want the warnings, use this:

```
Object o = new Double(42);
Value<Object> v = new Value<Object>("theAnswer");
```

Comment: ok, i guess i'll have to stick with Objects + casting (which is possible because the systems know what type of parameters they need)

Comment: This doesn't really address the OP's central question.  It just substitutes `Object` for a type, which breaks the reason for using generics in the first place.

Comment: I don't think the OP's question is well specified enough for this answer to be applicable.  We need to understand what s/he is trying to accomplish in order to suggest a better alternative.

Comment: i added a comment above, to specify what i would like to achieve.